# Generate Unique UPC/String in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, logic

I'm working on a point-of-sale system that uses unique alphanumeric UPC codes as an identity column in the database. The user is allowed to enter any alphanumeric UPC code that they want. I want to implement an auto-generate option for the UPC using C# and Linq to Entity, but am having some trouble with the logic. I'm trying to get it into the format 'A0000000010', where 'A' would denote the product type, and the numbers after are either random, or a counted number, they really don't matter. Here's my basic schema

```
productID  |  description  |  UPC
   1       |   ItemNum1    | 12345
   2       |   ItemNum2    | ABCDE
```

I can easily create a random number and attach it to the letter, then check if it exists in the database, and if it does, try it again, and again and again, but a brute force method seems like it could take a lot of time down the road, so I'd like to avoid this.

I also thought I could grab the last productID column (2 in this case), increment it (now it's 3), attach the requisite 0's (0000000003), and then attach the correct letter (A0000000003), but since users can create their own UPC's by hand, or by scanning, they could easily type in a UPC like 'A0000000015' that would affect this down the line.

To get around that, I could do something where if the UPC already exists, decrement the id (so A0000000003 would become A0000000002), and try again, and again, and again, and now we're back at the brute force method, albeit a much faster one.

My question is: Is there a way, using C# and Linq to Entity, to generate a string that is guaranteed not to exist in the database?

Comment: why now use var `newUpc = Guid.NewGuid()` and then from there if you want the values without `-` for example use the string.Replace function can you show some actual code that you have tried so that we can see how you are initially creating the unique value

Comment: If I do the `Guid.NewGuid()`, it would be greater than 11 characters, and so if I just strip it down to the length I need, I'm not longer able to guarantee that it's unique. If `Guid.NewGuid()` had a length option, it would be absolutely perfect.

Comment: I am sure you can make that work by that you could store the whole value and compare to see if it works and then have a second column in the database that would map that value to the new 11 character value thus insuring it would be unique. or keep a 3rd column to append or prepend to that value if it did exist thus making it again unique..

Comment: check out this and play around with it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14403/Generating-Unique-Keys-in-Net

Comment: Each product already does have a unique GUID. So it's already mapped and tied back to the unique 11 character UPC. And by appending/prepending a certain string, it would only guarantee this if EVERY UPC was autogenerated -- since User's can input their own UPC's, it wouldn't be hard for them to accidentily type in a GUID, or for the GUID to match an actual valid UPC. For example, in the 1,500 products we currently have, the string 018AEFF6 already shows up twice as the start to a GUID. I'll keep playing around with your suggestion though, I might get it to work!